# mysql_fetch_array is not retrieving result for php mailing

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to send the passengers location to the drivers email. The `$loc` variable is not fetching the location for some reason. When the user submits the form it gets the passengers name and then `$search_loc['location']` should get location from db of that name selected within the option tags. Thank you for your help.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="hidden"; // Mysql username 
$password="hidden"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="hidden"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="pickuprequests"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name", $link)or die("cannot select DB");

//names of the passengers in option tags
$name = $_POST['name'];

//this query gets all the records from pickuprequests of the passenger selected
$query="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE name = '$name'";
$result=mysql_query($result, $link);

// get the location of the passenger from $result
$search_loc = mysql_fetch_array($query, $link);
$loc = $search_loc['location'];


//find how many rows are returned with the passenger name
$search_row = mysql_query($query, $link);
$count = mysql_num_rows($search_row, $link);

//deletes a record assoc with passenger name
$delete_query = "DELETE FROM pickuprequests WHERE name = '$name'";

/* THIS IS CODE THAT HAS BEEN COMMENTED OUT
$altloc = $_POST['altloc'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
*/

//message for the passenger
$msg_passenger = "Your driver is on the way! You will receive one last email when the driver arrives.";
$subject_passenger = "Driver on the way";
$mailheaders = "From: TripoZipo <tripozipo.com> \r\n";

//passengers email
$search_email = mysql_fetch_array($result, $link);
$email = $search_email['email']; // this wont get the passengers email as well

//message for the driver
$msg_driver = "".$name." is located at".$loc.""; // the problem is that this wont display loc in email
$subject_driver = "Passenger Location";

//drivers email is the session name for driver.php
$driver = $_SESSION['driver'];

//on submit and if a passenger is selected run code
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {

    //$count returns all the rows assoc with passenger name
    if($count) {
    mail($email, $subject_passenger, $msg_passenger, $mailheaders); // email passenger your ride is on the way
    mail($driver, $subject_driver, $msg_driver, $mailheaders); // email driver the location
    //mysql_query($delete_query, $link); // finally delete the request as its not pending anymore
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'http://mobile.tripozipo.com/confirmation2.php'; </script>";
    }
    else {  //else if no rows are returned
    mail($email, $subject_passenger, $msg_passenger, $mailheaders); // email passenger your ride is on the way
    mail($driver, $subject_driver, $msg_driver, $mailheaders); // email driver the location
    //mysql_query($delete_query, $link); // delete pickup request so its no longer available
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'http://mobile.tripozipo.com/confirmation2.php'; </script>";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Change `$search_loc = mysql_fetch_array($query, $link);` to `$search_loc = mysql_fetch_array($result, $link);`

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_` database extensions. They are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the comment I will check out the manuel. However, you are right it should be $result but that is still not working. Why is $search_loc not sending result to the drivers email?

Comment: Add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not. Also wrap your `mail()` function inside if-else block like this, `if(mail(...)){ echo "success"; }else{ echo "failure"; }`

Comment: This code is so insecure.

Comment: Do some basic debugging. What does `var_dump($search_loc);` show?

Comment: Thank you guys for all your responses. I was able to figure out the underlying issue by using some debugging techniques you guys provided. var_dump helped and so did error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini set('display_errors',1), I am not too familiar with php and will be using those a lot more!